# How to use elements which are not in the second List<>()

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists like this List... In first I have some elements and I want to use a element in the second list which is not one of the first using LINQ. For example:

List one has: 1, 2
List two has: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

So my output should be: 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could do that with a foreach loop, no you shouldn't do it this way. What yolu should do is read about IEquatable and override the Equals method. This will let you control the property which excludes the elements.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) to subtract the first list from the second one.

```
var list3 = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

Comment: I can not use this because I get this error: Does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Except... @patrick

Comment: Add an `using System.Linq;` on top of your file.

Comment: My list is not of type int... I just made a example how should it look. @Patrick

Comment: I didn't say it was an integer, did I? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I have System.Linq

Comment: Is there a way to do this via foreach loop?

Comment: Then most likely the generic type parameters do not match.

Comment: Well, yes, but that won't help as long as the problem with non-matching types still exist.

Comment: What is type of objects stored in this `List`? I'm guessing, that you have to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` in this class.

Comment: @JackDawson Then you'd better provide more realistic example. The above answers your question as it is now, so you should accept it and post another question presenting your real case.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Except` method:

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
List<int> b = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = b.Except(a).ToList();
```

Comment: I can not use this because I get this error: Does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Except...

Comment: Add an `using System.Linq;` on top of your file. @JackDawson

Comment: That is not solving my problem. Is there a way to do this via fooreach loop?

Comment: @JackDawson as Patrick said, this is just a matter of matching the types